# Why can't my validator of element-ui-form be called?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Here are codes：

```js
**validateCode:[{validator:(rule, value, callback)=>{
    if (!value) { 
      callback(new Error('you have to input code')) 
    } else if(this.radioValue=="mobile"){
      validatingCo(this.user.mobile,value).then((res)=>{
        if(!res.code==20000){
           return callback(new Error('the code is wrong or expired'))
         } else{
             callback()
         }
      })
    }
    else{
       validatingCo(this.user.email,value).then((res)=>{
         if(!res.code==20000){
           return  callback(new Error('the code is wrong or expired'))
         } else{
           callback()
         }
       })
    }
  }, trigger:'blur'}]
```

Unfortunately, it didn't execute and no error.
I want to know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be caused by this line:

```
if(!res.code==20000){
  // Some stuff here
}
```

It should probably read:

```
if(res.code!=20000){
  // Some stuff here
}
```

`!res.code` will always evaluate to either `true` or `false`. So `!res.code==20000` will always be false. No matter the input the following error callback will never execute:

```
return callback(new Error('the code is wrong or expired'))
```

Here's a little demo to show that "bar" will always be printed out

```js
function simple_if(number) {
  if (!number == 20000) {
    return "foo"
  } else {
    return "bar"
  }
}

console.log(`res=20000. Expect 'bar': ${simple_if(2000)}`)
console.log(`res=3. Expect 'foo': ${simple_if(3)}`)
console.log(`res=0. Expect 'foo': ${simple_if(0)}`)
```